# How to enable Javascript in Midori

Tags: midori

I don't know I was messing(turning them on and off to see some visual changes) around with some of the extensions in Midori but then I noticed that Javascript got disable.

I turned off all the extension in Midori. Restarted Midro but nothing happened. Javascript was still disabled.

```
$midori -e enable-javascript=true
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

(midori:4318): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(midori:4318): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(midori:4318): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(midori:4318): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(midori:4318): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Vector smash protection is enabled.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to terminal and paste the below command, worked for me

```
echo "enable-scripts=true" >> ~/.config/midori/config
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable javascript run the following command in the terminal:

```
midori -e enable-javascript=true
```

For more information check this link: http://midori-browser.org/faqs/

Comment: doesn't work @shrestha_aj check the question